# React + axios + redux interceptors

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jwt, axios, interceptor

I have an React + redux + axios app, white jwt authentication. So, i need to intercept every request to server and set header with token. The question is where I have to set this headers, or implement interceptors. (also, i need redux store in scope, to get tokens from store). My idea - implement it in the Index component. Is it right way?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to set the header `axios.defaults.headers.common.authorization`. Take a look here [Global axios defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults). If you need a working example, [this](https://github.com/Remchi/bookworm-react) public repo can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to manually set the header. Can't you just store the JWT in a cookie and then the browser will forward it automatically for you. Just make sure you pass `credentials: 'include'` in your HTTP options.

Answer (score 0):

create a [`redux-middleware`](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) to do these things.

Apart from acting like `interceptor` to `add header token`,
you also do `request/response transformation`.

Also,you can mention the `next action` to which you want to `dispatch` the result if you don't want to return the promise and result.

`Middleware` gives you a chance `to get the store state` and also `fetch & dispatch other action`

```
const apiInterceptor = store => next => action => {

      if(action.type !== 'ajax') return next(action)

      const state = store.getState();

      state.token // get token here

      //add this api check part in some other module.
      if(action.api=='UPDATE_CLIENT') 
        {
          method = 'post';
          url  = 'some url';
        }
      else
      {
        method = 'get';
        url  = 'other url';
      }


      fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers : 'add token here',
        body: JSON.stringify(action.body())
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => json)//either return result
      //OR dispatch the result
       .then(json => {

         dispatch({type:action.next_action,payload : json})        
       })
    }
```

**Integrate the middleware with store.**

```
import customMiddleware from './customMiddleware'
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(customMiddleware)
)
```

Comment: This breaks SRP, you can break this apart into request/response interceptors and have your api client just do the api calls, middleware is not required and is much simpler, cleaner and more testable solution if you dont use middleware

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but its getting a few views, so something like this would work nicely and is easily testable.

**apiclient.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { setRequestHeadersInterceptor } from './interceptors';

const apiClient = axios.create(
{
  baseUrl: 'https://my.api.com',
  timeout: 3000
});

apiClient.interceptors.request.use(setRequestHeadersInterceptor);

export default apiClient;
```

**interceptors.js**

```
export const setRequestHeadersInterceptor = config =>
{
   // have each interceptor do one thing - Single Responsibility Principle
};
```

you should store your auth details in a httpOnly secure cookie, the transmission to/from the server will be automatic then

Answer (score 0):

```
//  Interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
// success case here
    return response
}, function (error) {

// Global Error Handling here
//    showErrorToaster(error['message']);
    return Promise.reject(error.response.data)
})
```